# Is "subject to a theft" a thing?

Tags: word-usage, dictionaries

Is it acceptable to say something has been "subject to a theft"? The only use case I can find is in this [policy document](http://www.lloydsbank.com/assets/media/pdfs/insurance/car/third-party-fire-and-theft-policy-document.pdf) from Lloyds Bank. Has it been adopted elsewhere?

Comment: Any noun could reasonably be 'subject' to any action on it.

Comment: You’re right that that does not sound right to my ear.

Comment: Yes, there do seem to be certain restrictions on the 'be subject to' construction. ??My apple pie has been subject to being eaten by me.

Comment: The idiom is sposta be _subject to theft/removal/towing/`<Action Noun>`_, with no article. It means the same thing as _liable to_, and it is not a thing but a condition, the predicate adjective phrase of a clause. _Cars parked in unlighted lots are often subject to theft. Park at your own risk._

Answer (score 1):

To my ear it sounds not only like a clumsy way of avoiding the passive voice, but it sounds like it belongs in a poorly-written police report.  [image]

Comment: @Ray:  I just realized that my answer assume's you are familiar with Google's Ngram viewer.  It provides statistical information about English language usage.  If you are interested in learning more, just google "Ngram viewer."